# Having an issue running the Selenium application inside the docker

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

To run the Java Selenium application on a separate server I am attempting to build a Dockerfile install Chrome and use a headless way to run a browser. (This application provides a desired output when executed locally.) But when attempting to run the docker I receive this error.

Am I missing something in the docker build or the Java-based configurations provided.? How should chrome driver-related configurations be added?

**Update:** There also seems to be another way to run Chrome using selenium/standalone-chrome. Is it possible to integrate Chrome/selenium with another docker using this method? which is the preferred option of these two methods?

```
OS - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Docker version - Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
Java version - java version "17.0.4" 2022-07-19 LTS
Selenium version - 4.11.0
Chrome version - Google Chrome 120.0.6099.199
```

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: u/BeforeClass openBrowser
>
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.NoSuchDriverException: Unable to obtain:
> Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args:
> [--remote-allow-origins=*, --headless], extensions: [], prefs:
> {download.default_directory: report/}}}, error Command failed with
> code: 65, executed:
> [/tmp/selenium-manager246697546082813077936780283589629/selenium-manager,
> --browser, chrome, --output, json] request or response body error: operation timed out Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision:
> '040bc5406b' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64',
> os.version: '5.4.0-150-generic', java.version: '17.0.6' Driver info:
> driver.version: ChromeDriver
>
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getPath(DriverFinder.java:25)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getPath(DriverFinder.java:13)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.generateExecutor(ChromeDriver.java:99)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:88)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:83)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:72)
> at Infra.BasePage.openBrowser(BasePage.java:108)
>
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Command failed with
> code: 65, executed:
> [/tmp/selenium-manager246697546082813077936780283589629/selenium-manager,
> --browser, chrome, --output, json] request or response body error: operation timed out Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision:
> '040bc5406b' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64',
> os.version: '5.4.0-150-generic', java.version: '17.0.6' Driver info:
> driver.version: ChromeDriver at
> org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager.runCommand(SeleniumManager.java:151)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager.getDriverPath(SeleniumManager.java:273)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getPath(DriverFinder.java:22)

**This is the docker file used**

```
 FROM maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine AS builder
    
    WORKDIR /app
    RUN chmod -R 777 /app
    
    RUN apt update -y & apt install -y wget unzip
    ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    RUN apt-get install -y tzdata
    
    RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
    RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
    
    RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
    RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
    RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/
    
    COPY . .
    
    RUN mvn package -DskipTests
    
    FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.6_10-jdk@sha256:13817c2faa739c0351f97efabed0582a26e9e6745a6fb9c47d17f4365e56327d
    
    WORKDIR /app
    
    COPY report-automation.jar /app/report-automation.jar
    COPY src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF /app/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    COPY src /app/src
    COPY src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF /app/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    COPY src/main/resources/config.properties /app/config.properties
    COPY pom.xml /app/pom.xml
    COPY testng.xml /app/testng.xml
    COPY application.properties /app/application.properties
    COPY Configuration.xlsm /app/Configuration.xlsm
    COPY apache-maven-3.9.6/ /app/apache-maven-3.9.6/
    COPY Downloads /app/Downloads
    COPY Logs /app/Logs
    COPY report /app/report
    COPY Reports /app/Reports
    
    EXPOSE 8080
    
    ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "report-automation.jar"]
```

**Code level configurations as below**

```
@Listeners(ExtentReportListener.class)
public class BasePage {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    private final Properties config = new Properties();
    public static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BasePage.class);

    public ChromeOptions getOptions() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        Map<String, String> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", config.getProperty("absoluteDownloadLocation"));
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.addArguments("--headless");

        return options;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void openBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(getOptions());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void ClearFolders() throws IOException {
        File dictionary = new File(config.getProperty("absoluteDownloadLocation"));
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(dictionary);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void closeBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.quit();
        createBackUpFile();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If its installing chrome versions > 115 your --headless arg should be
--headless=new
If it infact should be --headless=new than your chrome binary is crashing on startup.